# What does this unix function?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

can you please help me to understand what does this piece of code exactly do?
I guess it takes two arguments from shell script that this is part of, but I cannot quite grasp meaning of lines with //, %% and ##. Thanks in advance, for your help.

```
getEnvVal()
{
    tNm=`grep $1 $2`
    tNm=${tNm//$1}
    tNm=${tNm%% }
    tNm=${tNm## }
    echo $tNm
}
```

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: I looked at your link, but it is missing explanation for // line of code and also there is no example, so I honestly do not understand provided explanation...

Comment: Can you please tell me what is your input ($1 and $2) and what the output of this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `` tNm=`grep $1 $2` `` **saves** the output of `grep` to a variable
- `tNm=${tNm//$1}` **removes** any occurrences of the *value* of `$1` from the variable
- `tNm=${tNm%% }` **removes** a single space from the end of the variable
- `tNm=${tNm## }` **removes** a single space from the beginning of the variable
- `echo $tNm` **prints** the variable value

I would not recommend you use this script, because there are many problems with it:

- Uses obsolete `` `foo` `` construct. You should use `$(foo)`.
- Strips newlines from the end of the `grep` output. To get the literal output from `grep` you'll have to use something like this:

  ```
  tNm=$(grep "$1" "$2"; printf x)
  tNm=${tNm%x}
  ```
- Variables are not [quoted properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).
- If `$1` contains any characters which have special meaning in Bash, `${tNm//$1}` will likely behave unexpectedly (thanks @chepner).
- The author probably meant to remove *multiple* spaces from the start and end of the lines:

  ```
  tNm=${tNm%% *}
  tNm=${tNm## *}
  ```
- `echo` would behave unexpectedly if the variable starts with a dash. Use `printf` instead.
- The variable name is not meaningful.

Comment: Two more potential problems: 1) `$1` is not quoted, so if the (assumed) regular expression is also a valid pattern, it will be expanded by the shell before `grep` sees it, and 2) `$1` is subsequently used as a pattern to modify the value of `tNm`. Assuming `$1` is a fixed string removes both of these concerns.

Comment: The advice about `echo` is generally correct, but depends on the actual shell in use (since `echo` is a built-in).  For example, bash is generally more robust with arguments starting with a hyphen than ksh.  In ksh88, `print --` is a better alternative, since `printf` is not a builtin.  Anyway `printf` would also suffer from leading hyphen issues if incorrectly used: try `var=-n;printf "$var"`